# Sitecore Intranet Portal creates several profile folders

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-intranet-portal

I'm using Sitecore Intranet Portal.

In our solution in backend Sitecore creates 2 folders G under UserInfo folder.

[image: Sitecore user profile structure]

Also we are storing additional folders under userprofile item and as a result when MoveProfileToCorrectPlace method in ProfileProvider is called userprofile is moved and all subfolders are lost.

Is it normal Sitecore Intranet Portal behaviour? Has anybody faced with this issue?